# How can I compile .cpp from my program?

Tags: c++, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, console

I use Visual Studio 2012 and I want to compile *hello.cpp* file from my own program.
Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

string exec(char* cmd) 
{
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    string result = "";
    while(!feof(pipe)) 
    {
        if(fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
    }
    _pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    //ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS installation.
    string res = exec("cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\VC && vcvarsall"); 
    cout<<res<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And I get: **Cannot determine the location of the VS installation.**

The problem is **vcvarsall.bat** can't find some environment variables.

Everything works when I run it from cmd, or .bat.
Here is working .bat:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall"
D:
cl hello.cpp
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: What environment variables can it not find? What environmental variables are referenced in your .bat file?

Comment: My .bat is only these 3 lines